# aws rds intermittently unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-rds

I have a mysql server hosted by AWS RDS, which is intermittently uncontactable. I've been doing a lot of development today on a page that, although hosted locally, executes a query against the remote server on each page load, and I've discovered that every few minutes, I suddenly can't reach the server - it only lasts for a few seconds, but during that time I get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server` from any attempt to reach it.

Existing, already open connections (i.e. from the command line client) are not affected, and can run queries as normal. It's only establishing a new connection that is impossible.

Why does this happen? How can I track down the cause?

Comment: Open a case with AWS technical support.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I would, but they charge for that, and I don't want to subscribe just to get one question answered. I've already tried posting in their forums and got no replies. So, how do I track down the cause of the problem?

Comment: Look at the "events" under your RDS console. That's the only place where things get logged.

Comment: Did you configure RDS security groups properly? Is your IP address changing? Doubt it, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a instance type too small, t1.micro and t2 instances can show that behavior sometimes. What instance-type are you using?

Your CPU capacity might be throttled, and that could be the reason you see intermittent performance.